# Как сделать checkout директории?

Tags: git, git-checkout

Всем Привет!

Как сделать `checkout` (не очень уверен, применимо ли это к git, в TortoiseGit такого слова нет, вместо него предлагается `clone`) репозитория ясно - необходимо указать адрес, типа https://github.com/lishnih/rsted.git. А можно ли извлечь заданную директорию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Нельзя**. git устроен так, что вы получаете полную копию репозитория. Только как скульптор можете: берёте камень, и убираете всё лишнее - скачайте всё, сотрите ненужное.

Если какая-то папка является самостоятельной единицей, её можно сделать отдельным репозиторием, и подключать как `submodule` — чекаутить и коммитить отдельно от остального проекта.

Comment: Да, вы правы!
Просто я думал, может, можно переключиться как-нить на любую папку (как на ревизию или таг).
Спасибо за ответ! ))

Answer (score 4):

**Можно!**

Начиная с Git 1.7.3 существует [sparse checkout](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) — возможность получить только указанные файлы, без всей рабочей области.

```
# Инициализируем новый репозиторий.

mkdir example
cd example
git init

# добавляем удаленный репозиторий. 
git remote add -f origin git@github.com:myname/repo.git

# разрешаем sparse checkout в конфигурации
git config core.sparsecheckout true

# теперь добавляем пути к папкам, которые хотим получить
echo path1 >>.git/info/sparse-checkout
echo path2/foo/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

# получаем запрошенные папки
git pull origin master

# проверяем:
ls

path1 path2
```

Конечно, вместо `master` можно тянуть из любой ветки или коммита.